# What are methods that affect their explicit parameters called?

Tags: c++, comments, vocabulary

I'm documenting some code in C++ right now, and one of the methods I intend to write will sort an array. It won't create a new array, though, it will sort the elements of the given array in place. I want to include a remark along the lines of, "if the original ordering was important to you, then don't use this method!" But I would rather say something like "sorts the given array... statically?!... dangerously!... with mutations!!!" that programmers like you would be able understand.

What word describes this sort of method?

**Bonus question**: can anyone recommend a tool for C++ that creates HTML documentation from specially formatted comments, like javadoc? My operating system of choice is Ubuntu.

*Edit*: I'm a student and my assignment is to sort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorts the given array *in-place*.

You are aware of `std::sort` and `std::stable_sort`, right?

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it obvious that a function modifies parameters because they are passed in as non-`const` references? (Shameless plug: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c/2139254#2139254) for what the exact parameter type signifies.)

And you're looking for [doxygen](http://doxygen.org).

Comment: I'm a student: we comment everything!

Answer (score 0):

You already said it: the correct term is "mutator".